# How to search Mercurial for a particular change?

Tags: mercurial

I added a function to file on an a branch I can't remember. I want to port that function to a different branch. How can I search Mercurial to find it?

I know the name of the function and the file I put it in.

---

I'm using TortoiseHg, and it's got a search bar at the top. I'm not sure which Mecurial command it's using internally..maybe `hg log`?

But so far I've got

```
 user('me') and file('glob:class/database.php') and ????('myfunctionname')
```

Not sure [what filter](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html) I can use to search diff contents.

Also, I don't really know how those filename patterns work, I seem to have to search from the base; can't I do an exact match on filename, excluding directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the [grep](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#grep) command is what you're looking for:

```
 hg grep 'myfunctionname' -r "user('me') and file('class/database.php')"
```

You can match a specific file in the `file` revset query by specifying its full path.  Use `**file.extension` to find any `file.extension` anywhere in the repository.  See the Mercurial docs on [file patterns](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#patterns) for more information.  They are a little unclear on how to match any file with a specific name anywhere in the repo, however, so you'll probably have to do experiment a little.